# Why do $\pi/2$ pulses make a $\pi$ pulse?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, atomic-physics, quantum-spin

This is the topic Ramsey interferometry. I want to do this without referencing the Bloch sphere, just with the Hamiltonian (given on wikipedia) and Time-Dependent Schrodinger Equation.

A pi/2 pulse in a two-level system is defined as a pulse that sends the ground state $$| g \rangle \rightarrow \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}( | g \rangle+| e \rangle).$$ Two of them are supposed to just give the excited state $| e \rangle$, ie a pi pulse.

Using this rule, if you compose two pi/2 pulses you then get something like $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}( | g \rangle+| e \rangle) \rightarrow \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}( \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(| g \rangle+| e \rangle) +| e \rangle).$$ I know time evolution of a Hamiltonian is needed, but I got that it only adds an overall phase and the same thing is found.

How the heck is this a pi pulse (supposed to be just $| e \rangle$)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A $\pi/2$-pulse can be represented by the unitary matrix

$$
U_{\pi/2}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1\\
-1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
and the ground and excited states by the vectors
$$|g\rangle=\begin{pmatrix}
0\\
1 
\end{pmatrix} \qquad\text{and}, \qquad|e\rangle=\begin{pmatrix}
1\\
0 
\end{pmatrix}.$$
Which makes the application of the $\pi/2$-pulse on the ground state
$$U_{\pi/2}|g\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(|g\rangle+|e\rangle\right).$$
Applying a second $\pi/2$-pulse gives
$$\begin{align}U_{\pi/2}U_{\pi/2}|g\rangle=&\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}U_{\pi/2}\left(|g\rangle+|e\rangle\right)\\
=&\frac{1}{2}\left(|g\rangle+|e\rangle +\left(-|g\rangle+|e\rangle\right)\right)\\
=&|e\rangle\end{align}
.$$

In your last transformation, you have not considered the application of the $\pi/2$-pulse on the excited state.

Comment: I had considered this, but I didn't think the pi/2 pulse should act on the excited state. Physically, we're sending in an excited E&M wave that excites a bunch of atoms in the ground state to some superposition excited state. I still don't understand, why does this action have to be unitary? I don't see a probability that has to be conserved (since the atom can release radiation). If you don't follow my logic, I can explain more clearly.

Comment: @MondoDuke A pi/2-pulse acts on the excited state through stimulated emission. I’m not sure where it is mentioned in the link that a pi/2-pulse doesn’t act on the excited state?

Comment: @jaime1989 yes, I removed the link which is maybe not kosher, you are right. Is there a reason why this action has to be unitary? Ie why does the probability of being in the ground or excited state have to be conserved when radiation is also possible, or are we assuming radiation is not possible?

Comment: @MondoDuke For the two level system the atom can only be in the ground or excited state, the sum of the probabilities being equal to unity. Since the application of the pulse only changes the probabilities of which state the atom should be in, and not the sum, it can only be a unitary operator. I assume by radiation you mean spontaneous emission, we normally choose a two level system with a very long excited state lifetime i.e greater than the inverse of the Rabi-frequency, this last point I'm unsure about and might be worth checking.